# How to buffer all print() of the multiprocessing.Process inside and external functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I use multiprocessing for some tasks with multiple `print()` indicators inside them, so I can see how the process started/worked/ended in cmd. But, some tasks are quicker/slower, so `print()` order is chaotic. I need to find a way how to show all `print()` at once at the end of the process.

Simplified example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def runner(px_id):
    print('Start'+str(px_id))

    if px_id > 1:
        sleep(2)
    elif px_id == 1:
        sleep(5)

    print('Middle'+str(px_id))

    if px_id > 1:
        sleep(2)
    elif px_id == 1:
        sleep(5)

    print('End'+str(px_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    px_list = [1, 2, 3]

    for px in px_list:
        p = Process(target=runner, args=(px,))
        p.start()
```

If I run this code now, I'll receive:

```
Start1
Start2
Start3
Middle2
Middle3
End2
End3
Middle1
End1
```

While I need something like:

```
Start2
Middle2
End2
Start3
Middle3
End3
Start1
Middle1
End1
```

I still need processes to be async (so can't use `join()`) but to print all print() at the end of a process. Grateful for any advice :)

**UPD:** Using an array for buffering function messages is an OK solution, still need some help with buffering solutions from external functions. I mean, if I use some function inside other function I can't buffer all `print()` manually, so looking for some more complex solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have each instance buffer the output in an internal buffer.  then output it at the end.  You could have the main thread go and save each started process in an array.  then wait on all three to finish and finally go and grab the internal buffer from each process in the array and print them serially.

Comment: Ok, will internal buffer work, if processes are created inside `while True` loop? I can just add '\n +' to string variable and then print big string in the end, but it looks a bit unnatural :)

Comment: Read again (mb), array idea looks like perfect solution.

Comment: Still, what about inner functions? I mean, I can buffer function messages inside an array, but if I use some external functions inside - I can't buffer external prints. Maybe there's some more complex solution? :)

Comment: as you get ready to spawn the process, pass in something like the item documented here:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO  

Then write into that object with its methods.  keep reference to that object passed in the same way you would the processes (in an array).  then go and iterate over the array of output objects retrieving the contents from each item and then printing them.

Comment: part of the trick is to use:  p.join()  on the items in the array to way on them all finishing.  you would add a for loop after the spawn of the process  that loops over the list of processes created and then waits on them.  example: if you create a procArray = [] and append the p (process) to it for the three spawned process then you can itereate over procArray with something like procArray[i].join() to wait on the processes finishing.

Comment: your waiting on all of them to finish so does not mater if 1st is last to finish,  it will exit join when it finishes and then the next two iterations will immediately return (if their function already finished).  once that is done iterate over the StringIO array of times and extract each of the functions output.  (remember you passed one into each of the calls but kept a reference to it in an array so you could iterate over them at the end.

Comment: Great thanks! I don't wait for processes to finish, they're endless (while True), still idea with StringIO to handle iteration results looks like Pythonic way to solve my problem, so you helped me much :)